# Devise change password with confirmation of current password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to create a form that will allow a user to change their password, but requires that they first input their old password. I followed the wiki for devise, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password and have the following form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_account, @user.user_account do |user_account| %> 
<p>Edit password for account: <%=  @user.user_account.email %></p> 
<div class="field">
  <%= user_account.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= user_account.password_field :current_password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= user_account.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= user_account.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= user_account.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= user_account.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= user_account.submit "Edit" %>
</div>
```

Here is the call to update in my user controller:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

However, I'm getting an undefined method `update_with_password' for user error. devise was added to the model user_account - could it be that user does not have access to the devise method for updating with password? Is there a way around this?

Comment: which devise modules have you in user model?

Comment: :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable. also they're all in user_account, not user

Comment: then try something like @user.user_account.update_with_password

Comment: I get this issue with that: unknown attribute 'user_account_attributes' for UserAccount

Comment: do you have any accessor for the attributes you are updating?

Comment: I have params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :middle_initial, :last_name, :phone_number, :date_of_birth, :address_1, 
        :address_2, :city, :zip_code, :image, :bar_number, :company, :position, :education, :qualifications, 
        :biography, :price, :video,
        user_employments_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :company, :position, :start_date, :end_date, :info], 
       user_educations_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :school, :start_date, :end_date, :info, :_destroy], 
       user_account_attributes: [:id, :email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :user_id, :_destroy])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100717/discussion-between-emerak-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

You can change into:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

It will validate your old password. I hope this work.

Comment: which part of this validates the old password? this just updates the user with the new parameters and signs them in.

Answer (score -1):

First, get the current_user.id of user then, in Devise gem, you can use update_with_password method to ask the current password and using strong parameter.

Its works on rails 4 and 5.

```
def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_with_password(password_params)
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private
def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```